# How would I draw a shadow under a widget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget, shadow

I am wondering how I would draw a shadow under a widget (which isn't the main widget, say, a label.) in Qt. Would I neeed use a stylesheet or would I code it (in C++)?

Answer (score 12):

Say you have a form and a label you want to cast a shadow from.

You can use [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html) like so:

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect *effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
effect->setBlurRadius(5);
effect->setXOffset(5);
effect->setYOffset(5);
effect->setColor(Qt::black);

label->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

And the effect would be:

[image]

The downside of this effect is that if you apply it to a widget, all its children will inherit it. This could be problematic if you apply the effect on a widget with a lot of widgets because it could slow down the rendering time. But for your example this is perfectly fine and recommended.

For more information about effects in `Qt` check the [QGraphicsEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicseffect.html) class from which `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` is also derived.

Answer (score 0):

QLabel inherits from [QFrame](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qframe.html#Shadow-enum). You can use that to create shadows.