# How do I add a box-shadow to an element in QT?

Tags: css, qt, user-interface

I tried to do: `this->setStyleSheet("-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);")` and I get the error: `Unknown property -webkit-box-shadow`. The same goes for `box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`. Box-shadow, however, renders fine in a QWebView. Is there no way to add this effect to normal elements?

Comment: What kind of widget is `this`?

Comment: A custom widget which extends `QFrame` (it has no custom paint event)

Comment: Not all CSS works on qwidgets. QSS shares syntax and many properties with CSS for the web but is not identical

Comment: i think you want to `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328251/how-would-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-widget-in-qt

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs for QFrame. There's a frame shadow property.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#Shadow-enum

Comment: it doesnt seem to be working: does this conflict with the stylesheets?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a effect for shadows. Now you can mix them and specify multiple shadows. They are also cut off if you specify a border-radius.

https://github.com/GvozdevLeonid/BoxShadow-in-PyQt-PySide